# Составить запрос на DQL со связями сущностей

Tags: symfony, sql, yml, doctrine, entity

Добрый день.

Нужно помощь в составлении запроса.
Есть таблица товаров и таблица категорий с двумя уровнями.
Прилагаю вырезки YML, по которым сгенерированы сущности в Symfony.

**Item**

```
manyToOne:
    category:
        targetEntity: Category
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: item
        joinColumns:
            category:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

В свою очередь

**Category**

```
oneToMany:
    childrenCategory:
        targetEntity: Category
        mappedBy: parentCategory
    item:
        targetEntity: Item
        mappedBy: category
manyToOne:
     parentCategory:
        targetEntity: Category
        cascade: {  }
        mappedBy: null
        inversedBy: childrenCategory
        joinColumns:
            parent_category:
                referencedColumnName: id
        orphanRemoval: false
```

Чтобы найти товары по конечной категории, тут все просто. Они есть в самой таблице item.

```
 $query = $query->where('i.category = :category')
                ->setParameter('category', $categoryId);
```

Но я хочу найти товары по родительской категории. В теории нам надо сделать join на category.id на item.category и потом добавить условие с моим parentId.

Набросал так:

```
$query = $query->join('i.category', 'c', 'WITH', 'i.id = c.parentCategory')
            ->where('c.parentCategory = :mainCategory')
            ->setParameter('mainCategory', $mainCategoryId);
```

В расшифровке запроса мы видим:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c0_.id AS id0, c0_.id AS id1 FROM crbr_item c0_ INNER JOIN crbr_category c1_ ON c0_.category = c1_.id AND (c0_.id = c1_.parent_category) WHERE c1_.parent_category = '20
```

Тут явно лишняя строка

```
 AND (c0_.id = c1_.parent_category)
```

Как от нее избавиться? Не хочется использовать чистый SQL, а все же DQL, тем более, что есть связи, включая выборку дочерних, и можно сделать по-уму. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В репозитории ваших Item-ов можно добавить такой метод

```
public function findByRootCategory(Category $category)
{
  if (null !== $category->getParent()) {
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException('The method works only with root categories.');
  }

  return $this->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->join('i.category', 'c')
    ->where('c.parent = :parent')
    ->setParameter('parent', $category);
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
  ;
}
```

Но это будет работать только в том случае, если уровень вложенности у вас является 2. Если нужно любой уровень вложенности, то удобней в каждой сущности хранить связь с root-овой категорией, но тут уже организация деревьев при помощи ссылки на parent не очень удобна будет. Стоит смотреть в сторону NestedSet-ов или MaterializedPath-ов.